# Custom validator dynamic ServerValidate using Reflection

Tags: asp.net, reflection, customvalidator

I have a UserControl which contains a TextBox and a CustomValidator.

I would like to set the CustomValidator.ServerValidate to a method in the page that contains the UserControl

I found this code which will allow me to dynamically set the custom validators validation function:

```
cusvCustom.ServerValidate += new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventHandler(MethodName);
```

The problem is that a string value won't work there. It needs to be a reference to the method. Is it possible to use reflection (or some other method) to get a valid reference to the parent controls method using only the string name of it? The reason I want to use the string value of the method name is so I can place the control on the page thusly:

```
<uc1:TextBoxField ID="tbUserName" runat="server" CustomValidationMethod="ValidateUserName" />
```

I did some research and I found Type.GetMethod and MethodInfo but I can't get them to work. Primarily because I don't know the type of the parent control and can't figure out how to get it.

EDIT: My code for matt-dot-net

WebUserControl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebUserControl" %>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Custom Validation Failed" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="true" />
```

WebUsecControl.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public ServerValidateEventHandler Validating;

        protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Validating != null)
                Validating(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

TestPage.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.TestPage" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl.ascx" TagName="WebUserControl" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" OnValidating="WebUserControl1_Validating" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

TestPage.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class TestPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //WebUserControl1.Validating += WebUserControl1_Validating;
        }

        protected void WebUserControl1_Validating(Object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
        {
            e.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it's almost an exact duplicate of your code. For whatever reason it does not work for me as I have it here. When I click on the button the page reloads and is the same. When I un-comment the one line though and click the button then I see the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do:

WebUserControl.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl" %>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Custom Validation Failed"
ControlToValidate="TextBox1" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="true" />
```

And in your code behind:

```
public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
     public event ServerValidateEventHandler Validating;

     protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
     {
         if (Validating != null)
             Validating(sender, e);
     }
 }
```

This will allow you to use the control on a page the way you want to:

```
<uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" OnValidating="WebUserControl1_Validating" />
```

Then in your .aspx.cs code behind:

```
protected void WebUserControl1_Validating(Object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
   //do validation here
}
```

Comment: This is actually exactly what I'm looking for and much simpler than how I was thinking it would be handled. The only issue I have at the moment is that it's not working. CustomValidator1_ServerValidate gets called but Validating is always null. Do you have any idea why? Also does OnValidating show up for you in intellisense? It isn't for me.

Comment: Validating will be null if you have not connected an event handler in your page code.

Comment: Hmm. Still being weird for me. I copied your code exactly and put "e.IsValid = false;" as my validation so it should always fail. I'm not sure why but it still doesn't work for me unless I add "WebUserControl1.Validating += WebUserControl1_Validating;" to the aspx page Page_Load method. I guess it get's the job done but it would be nice to not have to add to the page load method if possible.

Comment: AHA! The code you posted is missing the keyword "event" in "public event ServerValidateEventHandler Validating;" but the files you posted have it. When I added the keyword to my code it started working. Thank you!

Comment: oh man!  I'm so sorry - posting code on here with my IE8 browser is painstaking some time... i will edit.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: No problem :) It's always something simple. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for. It's much easier than I thought it was going to be.